# Cross-platform Duplex scanner with good support in Ubuntu?

Tags: scanner

I have tried Canon P-150 (review [here](http://lowerstrata.blogspot.com/2010/07/canon-p-150-and-linux.html)), it works to some extent in Windows but I also use many other systems such as Ubuntu so it would be convenient if I could use the same scanner over many computers. Any good open-source-supported duplex scanner in small size on this market? If I could find an open-sourced duplex scanner with proper support, I am pretty sure I could get it working over the different systems. Or is this a pipe-dream? What about if I contacted some printd -software in my server that loaded the proprietary bits every time making the "obfuscated" scanner more cross-platform-compatible? Any such project around? (I know that would not really solve the social problem of distrust between manufacturers and users -- but just a random idea to get the so-called "scanners" even to work.)

Comment: Found a driver [here](http://www.canon.fi/Support/Consumer_Products/products/scanners/Others/P-150.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:22-806065&page=1&type=download), `dpkg -i *.deb` then logs [here](http://pastebin.com/FSfVEwi9) and then tested sane/xsane/etc but cannot get the scanner still working, irritating. Ideas?

Comment: Also please outline which software you use for scanning: xsane, sane -- and what kind of things you downloaded from apt-get to get things working, thank you.

Comment: There are many great card scanners out there. Why are you looking for an open-sourced duplex scanner with support in Ubuntu? For what purpose you use this scanner?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware recommendation is off topic here. Please go to [HardwareRecs.SE] instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have very good personal experience with the HP digital senders. 
basically something similair to this this, http://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-9200c-Digital-Sender-Scanner-Only-21-051-scans-/170830490394?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27c64a6b1a#ht_500wt_1129

but there are plenty versions around.

I claim good compatibility since its a stand alone device.
Very nifty. It can send you the scanned files directly as emails (pretty platform independent) there is also an app that scans the file directly to a folder on your desktop (probably not as independent as the email feature)

Comment: How did you get it working? With Xsane? P-150 provides only Windows -execution files so P-150 with Wine `"Cannot confirm the connection to the scanner. Confirm that the scanner is connected properly."`

Comment: It looks lovely scanner 50 pages' container with duplex scanner? Did it work out of the box, please, outline steps -- I want to be sure the scanner works also with my Ubuntu.